# Java text file I/O

Tags: java, java-io

Which is the fast way to write text file in java?
At the moment i use this way to write a text file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream('FileName');                            
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dos, Charset.forName(this.config.getCharset())));
```

My file size will be up 3 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flush the buffer after significant chunk of data is written. FileOutputStream should be just enough for text files. There is no need for using [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Comment: I'm write one line at time, when i must flush the buffer?

Comment: BufferedWriter would eventually flush the buffer once it's filled up. It's 8192 bytes long by default. If you want it to be written quicker (now), flush it.

Comment: FileOutputStream is the fast way to write text file in java?

Comment: I would say it is the only, unless you use some C library over JNI.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream('FileName');
BufferedOutputStream bof = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bof.write("some text".getBytes()); // or just byte array
```

or

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
  out.write("Some text");
```

You do not need to use DataOutputStream here.

Comment: RandomAccessFile is better then FileWriter?

Comment: what do you mean by "better"? Faster?